# How to verify if NHibernate hbm.xml are matching with a particular SQL schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, database-schema

I had an ASP.NET MVC web application, using NHibernate as ORM on SQL Server 2008 R2. When we deployed to the server, we can update our database any time (some are ad-hoc changes).

The problem is when the database schema change, the application crashed because NHibernate .hbm.xml files are no longer matching with the DB schema.

How do I verify that my current *.hbm.xml file are matching with the database schema ? And how to detect the mismatch early in ASP.NET MVC ?

Comment: how do you get the database schema ?

Comment: We have the template database schema stored in the master server. Then copies of the master database are deployed to slave server. 

Currently when we build the web app, the build server connect to the master server and generate the .hbm.xml files based on master server.

When we deployed, the application server connects to some database slave servers. There are times when the slave servers are not the same as master database (due to failed update tasks or manual changes). Thus the app crashed.

Comment: Is there a way that the application is able to get the database schema name (for example from web.config, either connection string key or app key) ? If that's possible, all you need to do just read the hbm file, read the schema attribute, then compare the value with the key.

Comment: Thanks @YuliamChandra, the app has connection string to slave db server. I'll try your suggestion, but I worried it would have performance impact. Probably I should only do the comparison once in `Application_Start` ?

Comment: correct, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do the checking when application runs, could be in the global asax.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
}
```

The connection string is the key to get the expected schema.

```
<property name="connection.connection_string">Server=.;Initial Catalog=TheExpectedSchema; ..</property>
```

First read the expected schema by reading it from nhibernate config and retrieve it from `Initial Catalog` part (if the database is oracle, probably use the `User ID` part).

```
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config = ...;

var conStr = config.Properties["connection.connection_string"];
var match = Regex.Match(conStr, "Initial Catalog *= *([^;]*) *");
var expectedSchema = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Then read the actual schema by reading it from `*.hbm.xml` file.

```
<hibernate-mapping schema="TheActualSchema"
```

If the files are put under `App_Data` directory, read each file and use xml document to get the schema.

```
var appDataDir = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"));
var files = appDataDir.GetFiles("*.hbm.xml");
foreach (var file in files)
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(file.FullName);

    var actualSchema = doc.DocumentElement.GetAttribute("schema");
    if (actualSchema != expectedSchema)
    {
        // Proper handling here (an example would be throwing exception).
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Expected schema: {0}, actual schema {1}", expectedSchema, actualSchema));
    }
}
```